# use std::accumulate to add an array to only a vector slice

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, c++14

I have following code

```
  std::vector<float> d; 
  d.resize(800); 


  std::array<float, 8> adder;

   int ind_slice = 5; // we want to add the array adder to v[40],v[41] ... v[47] 

   const auto it_begin = d.begin() + ind_slice *8;
   const auto it_end = d.begin() + ind_slice *8 + ind_slice;
   int index = 0;
   std::accumulate(it_begin, it_end) [&] ( float* ind) { return ind = ind + (adder[index++])};
```

I am wondering if this is a safe way to do the accumulation, since I am captuing a reference from the outside and mutating it. So the function does have side effects. Is there a better way to use the accumulate to achieve my objective

Comment: `// we want to add the array adder to v[40],v[41] ... v[47]` isn't `ind_slice` supposed to be `8` in this case?

Comment: Does `std::accumulate(it_begin, it_end)` successfully compile for you?  There is no form of that function that takes two parameters.

Comment: Why do you need to use `std::accumulate`? (You don't seem interested in the accumulated value.) Wouldn't `std::transform` serve you better?

Comment: ..or a simple loop.

Comment: The syntax in the code you present is so wrong it is not clear what your intent is. Post a version that actually compiles, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least if I understand your intent correctly, the algorithm to use here would almost certainly be `std::transform`, not `std::accumulate`.

`accumulate` is intended for taking some collection, and simply adding them up, roughly equivalent to `sum()` in a spreadsheet (for one example).

`transform` allows you (among other things) to combine two collections, about the way you seem to want to.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<float> d; 
    d.resize(800); 

    std::array<float, 8> adder { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    size_t start = 40;
    const auto it_begin = d.begin() + start;
    const auto it_end = d.begin() + start + adder.size(); 

    // do the addition:
    std:transform(it_begin, it_end, adder.begin(), it_begin, [](float a, float b) { return a + b; });

    // show the modified part of the array.
    std::copy(it_begin, it_end, std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

I've taken the liberty of simplifying a bit of the other code as well, but not in ways that are likely to matter much here.

Since you only need an iterator to the beginning of the second collection, you can simplify the code a bit further if you want, by using `adder` as the first collection, and the slice of `d` as the second:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<float> d; 
    d.resize(800); 

    std::array<float, 8> adder { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    size_t start = 40;
    const auto it_begin = d.begin() + start;

    std:transform(adder.begin(), adder.end(), it_begin, it_begin, [](float a, float b) { return a + b; });

    std::copy(it_begin, it_begin+adder.size(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

As it stands right now, we still use an iterator to the end of the affected portion of `d` when we print things out, but that was added just to make it clear that we'd actually done something, not to fulfill any real requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11 the binary operator passed to `std::accumulate` is allowed to have side effects. The restrictions since C++11 are (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)):

> op must not invalidate any iterators, including the end iterators, nor modify any elements of the range involved, nor *last.

In general, standard algorithms are permitted to copy functors passed to them, but this isnt an issue with your operator either.

The problem is that the functor passed to `std::accumulate` must be a binary operator that specifies how each element is accumulated to the resulting value. Yours is not a binary operator and it will simply not compile. It is not clear why you want to use `std::accumulate` when you do not want to accumulate something. A simple loop will do:

```
for (size_t i=0;i<8;++i) d[i+40] += adder[i];
```